# Checking users who have only one activity on a job in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called activities.
The Admin gives users Some job With unique code to do.
when a user doing something on one of his jobs. user add one record on table with 
unique code job and user_id.
I want to count the number of jobs the user has just done an activity on that.
I want to show something like this :

```
user_id | Count Jobs with one activity
1       | 5
2       | 7
 .....
```

in this case user with id 1 has 5 jobs that he just do one activity on it.
* one job is blong to one user and another user can not do activity on it.

I'm sorry if my english is not good

[there is a sample of activities table :](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8322046526/tbl_activities.png)

Comment: show us sample data with user_id and job_code. thanks

Comment: I edited and add activities table to the post.

Comment: Using your sample actvities table, is this your expected result? user_id | Count jobs 1  | 2    2 |  3 ?

Comment: Yes i want to get such result from activities table

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as Job_counts
FROM activity_table
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks.but I don't want job count I want count the jobs that only has one activity on it

Comment: What is your expected result based on your sample data?